# Changing href of Tweet button?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to place a tweet button on a website; the tweet will be pre-populated with text that changes depending on the text in a div (which can be changed by the user). The normal href value is https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=whatever-text-here, but since I need the pre-populated text to change based on certain conditions, I tried to add an onClick function. For now, I'm just trying to change the href to "...text=" + "whatever-text-here" to see if things work, but in the future, I need to change it to "...text=" + someVariable.

I'm very new to this; can someone explain why this doesn't work? Here's a link to the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbdQyW).

HTML:

```
<a class="twitter-share-button"
  href="#" onclick="tweetContent()";
  data-size="large">
Tweet</a>
```

JS:

```
function tweetContent() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-share-button").href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + "quote";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName` (as in the name) return `Elements` (in plural, not singular).

You will need to go over them, one by one, and set the href attribute:

```
function tweetContent() {
    var anchorElements = document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-share-button")
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchorElements, function(e) {
        e.href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + "quote";
    })
}
```

Here is a working example:

```js
function tweetContent() {
  var anchorElements = document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-share-button")
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchorElements, function(e) {
    e.href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + "quote";
  })
}

tweetContent()
```

```html
<a href="" class="twitter-share-button">a</a>
<a href="" class="twitter-share-button">b</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Changed my code, but unfortunately still doesn't work.

Comment: I added your code, but nothing changes—when I click the tweet button in codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbdQyW), there is no pre-populated text.

The code makes sense, and the code snippet works; is this something specific to the button I pulled from Twitter, i.e. there's something underlying in widgets.js that tells the button what to do?

Comment: The javascript inside the codepen you provided is not the javascript in this specific question. My answer gives the exact solution based on your question, so please accept this answer.